# Relation between $\sigma (N)$, $\tau (N)$, and $\varphi (N)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to prove
$$\sum\limits_{d\mid n} {\sigma (d)\varphi (n/d) = n\tau (n)}$$
and
$$\sum\limits_{d\mid n} {\tau (d)\varphi (n/d) = \sigma (n)}$$
where
${\sigma (N)}$ is the divisor function, ${\tau (N)}$ is the number of positive divisors of $N$, and $\varphi (N)$ is Euler's totient? I am looking for a short proof.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [Dirichlet convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution):
$$
\sum\limits_{d\mid n} \sigma (d)\varphi (n/d) = (\sigma * \varphi) (n) = (u * N * \mu * N)(n) = (N * N)(n) = n \tau(n)
$$
where $u(n)=1$ and $N(n)=n$. By definition, $\sigma = u*N$. It's a famous (but easy) theorem  that $N=u*\varphi$, from which follows that $\varphi = \mu * N$, since $u$ and $\mu$ are Dirichlet inverses (that's essentially Moebius inversion formula).

The second one follows in the same way:
$$
\sum\limits_{d\mid n} \tau (d)\varphi (n/d) = (\tau*\phi)(n) = (u*u*\mu*N)(n) = (u*N)(n)=\sigma (n)
$$
since $\tau = u*u$.

Comment: Wow! Not only did you answer my question you actually taught me something I did not know. You see, the book we are using does not use the convolution notation $f*g$, nor does it use the identity map $N$ or the unit function $u$, which are extremely convenient as your answer shows. I wish I could upvote your answer more than once. Thanks!

Comment: @glebovg, see for instance Chapter 2 of Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory*. An excellent book. Which book are you using?

Comment: OK. We are using *Elementary Number Theory* by Burton (undergrad number theory). We covered Mobius inversion, but the author does not mention Drichlet convolution, $N$, $u$, etc.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** In all cases, the left side and the right side are **multiplicative.** So it is enough to verify things for prime powers, where computation is easy.

Comment: I prefer this answer, since it's the most elementary.